# Apply Cartoonizer effect in Android

Tags: android, image, effect

I am trying to achieve a cartoon style effect on photos using Android, but I don't really have any idea where to start.  What sort of algorithm should I think about using to achieve the desired effect.

I have included a before and after shot to show you what I am looking for.

**Before** 
[image]
**After**
[image]

Any ideas how I can go about achieving this?

Comment: Please ask a specific question, show us what you tried and where you are stuck. you're not going to get the complete code here.

Comment: I tried with Gaussian blur and other option of Canvas and Bitmap. But as I post link of Image (2nd) , that I didn't get.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/143355/Cartoonizer-Convert-Photos-into-Cartoon-Like-Image - that project is in VB but they also explain the filters/transformations they use, that should get you started.

Comment: Although the question does come across a little rude, it is completely clear what is being asked, its not vague, not incomplete etc etc, so why was this closed?  Another over reaction by moderators.  Why not just ask him to modify his question or modify it for him, it would have taken less than a minute to do.

Comment: @I really don't understand how this question is not constructive.Such moderators should be banned....

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve an effect like this by approximating each texel to the nearest colour in some sort of array.  It's only a very basic approach but its a good starting point.